# Why do I get weird output in printf in awk for $0?

Tags: bash, awk, printf

The input is following

```
Title: Aoo Boo

Author: First Last
```

I am trying to output

```
Aoo Boo, First Last, "
```

by using awk like this

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="[:[:space:]]+" }
/Title/ { sub(/^Title: /,""); t = $0; } # save title
/Author/{ sub(/^Author: /,""); printf "%s,%s,\"\n", t, $0} 
' t.txt
```

But the output is like ,"irst Last. Basically it prints everything from the beginning of the sentence.

But if I change $0 to $2, the output is as expected which is `Boo,Last,"`

Why is it incorrect? What is the right way to do?

Comment: change the FS value to `FS=":[[:space:]]+"`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Still not working :(

Comment: did you try this `awk -v FS=": +" '/^Title:/{p=$2}/^Author:/{s=$2;print p", "s", \""}' file`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj But I want to output Aoo Boo, First Last, " not just Boo, Last, "

Comment: no it works for me. We said the fs value to `:+one or more spaces` not `:or one or more spaces` . `[:[:space:]]+` means colon or space one or more times.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get rid of the Windows line endings in your text file if you want to use Unix utilities.

If you're lucky, you'll find you have the `dos2unix` program installed, and you'll only need to do this:

```
dos2unix t.txt
```

If not, you could do it with `tr`:

```
tr -d '\r' < t.txt > new_t.txt
```

---

For reference, what is going on is that Windows files have `\r\n` at the end of every line (actually, a <kbd>CR</kbd> control code followed by a <kbd>NL</kbd> control code). On Linux, the lines ends with the `\n`, so the `\r` is part of the data; when you print it out, the terminal interprets as a "carriage return", which moves the cursor to the beginning of the current line, rather than advancing to the next line. Since the value of `t` ends with a `\r`, the following text overwrites the value of `t`.

It works with `$2` because you've reassigned `FS` to include `[:space:]`; that definition of field separators is more generous than the awk default, since it includes `\r` and `\f`, neither of which are default field separators. Consequently, `$2` does not contain the `\r`, but `$0` does.

Comment: @jaypalsingh: The output "starting" with `,"` was a dead giveaway.

Comment: Is there any other way I can output the same thing without getting rid of \r? This will make my other parts of code totally fail

Comment: @user3362840: Your program is outputing what you expect it to output. What is unexpected is the way that it is displayed. If you need the `\r` in the output, then there is nothing wrong except for visibility (which you can fix by piping through the provided `tr` command). It's not obvious to me why changing a file to unix format will totally break your code, but I suppose it is clear to you, which is what is important. (`hd` is your friend, by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

This assumes there are no colons in titles or names...

```
awk -F': *' '
  $1=="Title" {
    sub(/[^[:print:]]/,"");
    t=$2;
  }
  $1=="Author" {
    sub(/[^[:print:]]/,"");
    printf("%s, %s\n", t, $2);
  }
' inputfile.txt
```

This works by finding the title and storing it in a variable, then finding the author and using that as a trigger to print everything according to your format.  You can alter the format as you see fit.

It may break if there are extra colons on the line, as the colon is being used to split fields.  It may also break if your input doesn't match your example.

Perhaps the most important thing in this example is the `sub(...)` functions, which strip off non-printable characters like the carriage return that rici noticed you have.  The regular expression `[^[:print:]]` matches "printable" characters, which the carriage return is not.  This script will **sub**stitute them into oblivion if they're there, but should do no harm if they are not.